# The truth value of a series is ambiguous: use

Tags: python, pandas

I get an error stating

> ValueError:The truth value of a series is ambiguous for the if
>   condition.

with the the following function:

```
for i , row in train_news.iterrows():
if train_news.iloc[:,0].isin(['mostly-true','half-true','true']):
    train_news.iloc[:,0] = "true"
else :
    train_news.iloc[:,0] = "false"
```

Comment: What's the data?, what's the desired output?

Comment: You dont need a for loop and if condition until necessary but to answer that a better way you need to provide the dataFrame and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `if` statement -

```
if train_news.iloc[:,0].isin(['mostly-true','half-true','true'])
```

Think about what this does -

Let's say `train_news.iloc[:,0]` looks like this -

```
mostly-true
not-true
half-true
```

Now if you do `train_news.iloc[:,0].isin(['mostly-true','half-true','true'])`, this will check iteratively whether each element is present in the list `['mostly-true','half-true','true']`

So, this will yield another `pandas.Series` which looks like this -

```
True
False
True
```

The `if` statement in python, being the simpleton, expects one `bool` value and you are just confusing it by providing a bunch of boolean values. So, either you need to use `.all()` or `.any()` (those are the usual to-do things) at the end depending upon what you want